# How can I simulate a different button pressed when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible using vue.js to simulate another button pressed when a button is pressed?

For example, if I press the <kbd>↓</kbd> (Arrow down) button, I would like it to be represented as if I had pressed the <kbd>TAB</kbd> button.

**Explanation why am I trying to implement this:**

After clicking on a DropDown list, the list with all the elements opens up. In this list I have an `<input>` element as a search box, which is used to search other elements in the list (all the other elements are directly listed under that search box). Currently as the DropDown list opens the focus is set automatically to the search box. To go down to the next item, you have to press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> button. But I need to achieve this with the <kbd>↓</kbd> (Arrow down) button.

Comment: Are you talking about keypress events? Can you describe your problem a little more fully?

Comment: There, I have edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* you're asking how to simulate a <kbd>TAB</kbd> keypress when the user presses <kbd>DOWN</kbd> with the goal of moving the focus to the next focusable input.

Instead of rewriting the `key`-event, you could call [`HTMLElement#focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on the next sibling:

```
<!-- TEMPLATE -->
<input type="text"
    @keydown.up.stop.prevent="prevInput"
    @keydown.down.stop.prevent="nextInput"
    v-for="i in 5">

// SCRIPT
methods: {
  nextInput(e) {
    const next = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
    if (next) {
      next.focus();
    }
  },
  prevInput(e) {
    const prev = e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling;
    if (prev) {
      prev.focus();
    }
  },
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text"
         @keydown.up.stop.prevent="prevInput"
         @keydown.down.stop.prevent="nextInput"
         v-for="i in 5">
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    nextInput(e) {
      const next = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
      if (next) {
        next.focus();
      }
    },
    prevInput(e) {
      const prev = e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling;
      if (prev) {
        prev.focus();
      }
    },
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Bro, you should wear cloak and shirt with letter `H` because YOU ARE MY HERO! Thanks for this answer, it works like a charm, and I never knew of these methods. There is so much that I can do using them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, add a ref to `tab`

```
<div class="tab" ref="tab">
```

Then capture arrow click:

```
arrowClick() {
   this.$refs.tab.click()
}
```

Comment: Getting an error with this syntax `Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs.tab.click is not a function`

Comment: That's because you don't emit click events this way, unless you're using jQuery. `$(this.$refs.tab).click()` would work, then, I think. Otherwise, you need to [create and dispatch an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events)

Comment: So there is no an easy way to do what I have asked in my question? What about `v-on:keyup.up="doSomething"` and then implement that function to do what I need?